# Record button in Instrument enabled for simulator but disabled for device

Tags: xcode4

I am using Instrument 4.0
Xcode 4.0.2

I used to be able to click record button to profile my app on my devices.

But now, it only works for simulator, but not for device!
the record button is disabled when i connect my ipad to profile my app on it...